# Wordpress site wont scrolling

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

One of my wordpress site wont scrolling on Chrome (Windows). Im a newbie, and cant tell you much, but this is happens when I update the theme version. The theme author is so futile and does not help me.

[This](http://moderendom.net) is the site.

Thanks in advance and again - sorry for а limited information.

Comment: I checked the site on Chrome. It's scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
#body-maha {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #212121;
}
```

Change it to:

```
#body-maha {
    overflow-x: auto;
    background: #212121;
}
```

Or remove it completely

Comment: I deleted it - is not working. Miss to say that scrolling works when hover with mouse the scrolling bar.